# Change permission on folder if it ends with string

Tags: batch-file

Currently I am trying to create a batch that will go through a long list of folders and I need to change only certain folders permissions. Only problem is when I run this it always uses the last folder in the tree and skips all the rest.

```js
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\Users\ash.taylor\Desktop\Proposals\*"') do (

  set folder="%%G"
  echo %folder%

  set ending = "%folder:~-14%"
  echo %ending%

  IF "%ENDING%" == "5.0.0-Drawings" ICACLS "%DIR%" /GRANT:R "User":M

)
```

So basically I want to get the last 14 chars of the dir and compare it to 5.0.0-Drawings and if that is true then add permission to that dir.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion.

1. Add `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` before your `FOR` loop.
2. Change variable references from `%folder%` to `!folder!` and `%ending%` to `!ending!`.
3. Remove spaces around the `=` in your `SET` statements.

For example:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\Users\ash.taylor\Desktop\Proposals\*"') do (

  set folder="%%G"
  echo !folder!

  set ending="!folder:~-14!"
  echo !ending!

  IF "!ENDING!" == "5.0.0-Drawings" ICACLS "%DIR%" /GRANT:R "User":M

)
```